# Problem with csv special characters

Tags: c#, datagridview, csv, datatable, char

I have a problem: I have read a csv file and store the contents into a datatable, and everything is ok. But when I show the contents of the datatable in a datagridview, when I have the symbols "€" or "is, and ..." I only see a diamond with a question mark inside. How can I fix this? thanks

Answer (score 7):

You need to load the file with correct encoding.

Default is UTF8 but your file could be ASCII.

pass the encoding to the constructor of `StreamReader` :

```
StreamReader sw = new StreamReader (fileName, Encoding.ASCII);
```

### Note

I do not know what encoding your file has but **I just guess it is ASCII**.

Comment: ok but I can not implement your suggestion. I have read a set of files and put them in a vector
string [] = filePaths Directory.GetFiles (@ "C: \", "*. csv");
How can I fix this?